# Interact with Locked Screen

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create own version of VNC, a very simple solution of it, and so far it's working.
Yet - I can not find a way to interact with the locked screen once the user lock the PC.

- How can I interact with locked screen ( take screenshots of it, move the mouse and press keys ) from a service on the recent Windows OS ?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to programmatically interact with Login-screen. This is done by design for security reasons. You could potentially replace default WinLogon program in order to allow communication with your service.

Comment: Arent't "locked" and "login" screen different things? The former displays the clock, the latter a textbox for the password. Likewise a separate service can be chosen instead of the "login" screen, but not both in parallel.

Comment: I am pretty sure that TeamViewer interact with the Lock/Login screen. Same goes for Anydesk, and  row of similar applications. So, there should be a way.

Comment: Such software would display remote desktops on the local desktop, and as such also remote login screens - then you're just talking about remote connections, while locally already being logged in. Is that what you mean? Not your PC with your login screen (which could also be offline)? Because transmitting and receiving input over internet is a whole different topic.